# How do you properly escape strings without PreparedStatement?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, jdbc, escaping

I'm using the Statement's for executeUpdate and executeQuery. The string values I'm concatenating into the SQL query can contain at least the `'\` character as well as Unicode.

PreparedStatement seems to do this automatically, but is there some utility function in the JDBC library to escape an arbitrary string for use in a SQL query?

Example errors I've ran into:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near
```

and

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid Unicode escape
  Hint: Unicode escapes must be \uXXXX or \UXXXXXXXX.
```

Comment: Why *not* prepared statements? :( Whenever I have done dynamic-SQL, the string is only dynamic wrt. the structure/schema and *not* the data. (It is just as easy to build up the placeholders/data-bindings with the dynamic-SQL string.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not part of JDBC, and it's different for different database management systems. You should really use `PreparedStatement` for queries with parameters. This is more secure and it can perform better since the query can be compiled.

See [4.1. SQL Syntax - Lexical Structure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) in the PostgreSQL manual.

E.g.

> The following less trivial example writes the Russian word "slon" (elephant) in Cyrillic letters:

```
U&"\0441\043B\043E\043D"
```

Comment: Thanks! Tho technically, it is part of JDBC, since it internally does it.

Answer (score 1):

The way JDBC does it is:

QueryExecutorImpl.parseQuery()

- Breaks the string into fragments, handles single quotes, double quotes, line comments, block comments, dollar signs and takes note of ? for substitution.
- Creates a SimpleQuery object

SimpleParameterList

- Handles string encoding (UTF-8, bytea, etc.)

Unfortunately, to get the full string escaping (with encoding, handling of special chars, etc.), you'd probably need to somehow access and use `QueryExecutorImpl` and I wasn't able to figure out how to do that. `PreparedStatement` does internally use `QueryExecutorImpl`.

Conclusion, the best and easiest way is to probably use `PreparedStatement`.